# Traversing and printing complex Dictionary types (Scripting.Dictionary) - Dictionary inside of a Dictionary

Tags: vba, hash-map, excel, type-safety

Based on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909404/recursively-print-next-dictonaries-in-vba/25909642#25909642) - also reposted on [vba4all.com](http://vba4all.com/how-to-write-a-vba-collection-andor-dictionary-scripting-dictionary-to-a-spreadsheet/) with a few more details and explanations.

*Please notice there currently is no error handling whatsoever as I didn't analyse and consider any traps yet. Although feel free to supply details/code based on your assumptions. For Example - the code fails when you try to load duplicate keys into the dictionary... this can easily be handled with the OERN approach...*

So the tree would look like this for example

[image]

I have created a simple procedure `TraverseDictionary()` which traverses any structure of dictionaries.

The simplest version that prints *somehow* a logical structure to the Immediate Window:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim subDict As New Dictionary
    Dim lvlDict As New Dictionary

    lvlDict.Add "LVL KEY", "LVL ITEM"

    subDict.Add "HELLO", ":)"
    subDict.Add "WORLD", ":("
    subDict.Add "OTHER", lvlDict

    dict.Add "FOO", "BAR"
    dict.Add "BOO", subDict

    TraverseDictionary dict

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseDictionary(d As Dictionary)

    For Each Key In d.Keys
        Debug.Print "KEY: " & Key
        If VarType(d(Key)) = 9 Then
            TraverseDictionary d(Key)
        Else
            Debug.Print "ITEM: " & d(Key)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

with a result:

[image]

and w/ a print out to sheet with *somehow* even more logical view

```
Private i As Long
Private depth As Long

Sub Main()
Cells.ClearContents

    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim subDict As New Dictionary
    Dim lvlDict As New Dictionary

    lvlDict.Add "LVL KEY", "LVL ITEM"

    subDict.Add "HELLO", ":)"
    subDict.Add "WORLD", ":("
    subDict.Add "OTHER", lvlDict

    dict.Add "FOO", "BAR"
    dict.Add "BOO", subDict

    i = 1
    depth = 0
    TraverseDictionary dict

    Columns.AutoFit

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseDictionary(d As Dictionary)

    For Each Key In d.Keys
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, depth) = "KEY: " & Key
        If VarType(d(Key)) = 9 Then
            depth = depth + 1
            TraverseDictionary d(Key)
        Else
            Range("B" & i).Offset(0, depth) = "ITEM: " & d(Key)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

As mr. [Ioannis noticed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909404/recursively-print-next-dictonaries-in-vba/25909642#comment40596407_25909642)

> There is a small risk, if an Item of a dictionary is itself an object
>   but not a dictionary. Specifically, VarType(d(Key)) = 9 holds true for
>   Objects of any kind (I tried it with custom classes and it returned a
>   type mismatch error). I would suggest after checking for VarType, also
>   checking for dictionary specifically (eg, try to access a property and
>   trap the error)

Ok, so currently the code *works* with the assumption that the `Dictionary` is actually of `VarType = 9` but that breaks because of `Objects` which also return `9`.

If we check `TypeName(d(key)) = "Dictionary"`  then in *theory* it should only work with `Dictionaries` but can you think of any other approaches to actually check & possibly validate the `Dictionary`.

*Side note: In the future I am most likely to create a class wrapper for this and accumulate all the checks in there along with printing at different locations and to different views.*

Comment: This reminds me of the git object structure...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A couple of things, which you've really more or less pointed out already.

1. You've shown us two different implementations of the same routine that outputs two two different places. I think what you really need is a class that gets initialized with an `IOuput` member. Then you can have different implementations of the `IOuput` interface, but `TraverseDictionary` only has to deal with `IOutput` and one routine can print out to anywhere.
2. You're correct that `VarType = 9` is unsafe and `TypeName = "Dictionary"` is *safer*, but I'm not sure it's entirely safe. What if there's a namespace conflict because I implemented a `VBAProject.Dictionary`? `TypeName` of my custom dict would also be "Dictionary" and who knows what would happen then. `TypeOf` is another option though. I've not tested it, but I believe you can do this.

   ```
   If TypeOf d(Key) Is Scripting.Dictionary Then
   ```

   ***But*** that means you'll also have to check `IsObject(d(key))` prior to checking its actual type as well.

**Update:**

I finally had time to test this. I created an empty `Dictionary` class and ran the code below. It works.

```
Sub test()
    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim myDict As New VBAProject.Dictionary

    Debug.Print TypeOf dict Is Scripting.Dictionary
    'true
    Debug.Print TypeOf myDict Is Scripting.Dictionary
    'false
    Debug.Print TypeOf dict Is VBAProject.Dictionary
    'false
    Debug.Print TypeOf myDict Is VBAProject.Dictionary
    'true
End Sub
```

Comment: ++ and thanks. Your no. 2 is exactly my concern at the moment.

Comment: You're welcome. If you get to testing it before me, let me know if `TypeOf` can tell the difference.

Answer (score 4):

In your `TraverseDictionary` that uses worksheets as output, you reference as global variables, `i` (row) and `depth`.  You can encapsulate them in your procedure like this.

```
Private Sub TraverseDictionary(d As Dictionary, ByRef line As Integer, ByVal indent As Integer)
    For Each key In d.keys
        Cells(line, indent).value = key
        If VarType(d(key)) = 9 Then
            line = line + 1
            TraverseDictionary d(key), line, indent + 1
        Else
            Cells(line, indent + 1).value = d(key)
        End If
        line = line + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

This will allow for easier abstraction for your output.  If you go with RubberDuck's solution of implementing `IOutput` objects they will at least need some method of controlling the depth or indentation.  They should be able to control the line count on their own which will eliminate the need to keep track of it.

```
Private Sub TraverseDictionary(d As Dictionary, ByVal indent As Integer, ByRef ostream As IOutput)
    For Each key In d.keys
        ostream.PrintLine "Key: " & key, indent:=indent
        If VarType(d(key)) = 9 Then
            TraverseDictionary d(key), indent + 1, ostream
        Else
            ostream.PrintLine "Val: " & d(key), indent:=indent
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```